# Getting the second last item from .split created list

Tags: android, arrays, list, kotlin, split

As of right now I retrieved the last item in my list that I generated by using `split`, but I want to get the second last item. The reason is the list is generated from an ocr and is never the same length or size, but never empty or has less than 10 entries.

Is there a way in Kotlin to always get the second last item using `.split`?

This is the code for getting the last:

```
fun String.firstLine(): String {
if (this.isEmpty()) return ""
return this.split("\n").let {it.last()}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `it` a list of lines, use its `size` and get the item at the 2nd last index (size minus 2; since the last item is size-1). Or `lastIndex - 1`.

```kotlin
fun String.secondLastLine() =
    if (this.isBlank()) ""
    else this.trim().split("\n").let {
        if (it.size < 2) ""
        else it[it.size - 2]  // or it[it.lastIndex - 1]
    }

fun main() {
    val s = listOf("first line\nsecond line\nsecond last line\nlast line",
                   "only one",    // does not end with a newline
                   "only one\n",  // ends with a newline
                   "first\nsecond\nthird",
                   "",  // empty
                   "  \n \t  ", // blank
                   "first\nsecond")
    s.forEach { println(it.secondLastLine()) }
}
```

Output:

```
second last line


second


first
```

You've mentioned *"never the same length or size, but never empty or has less than 10 entries."* - I've added a check for that and returning an empty string if it's only 1 item. If it's not needed, you can remove that.

Comment: @dkiwikid You're welcome. Btw, I recommend adding a filter to each line after the split to remove blank lines. Also, I've replaced `isEmpty()` with `isBlank()` for the initial string check so that whitespace-only strings are skipped.

Answer (score 2):

If you known that the text always has 3+ lines, you can use very kotlin-style takeLast approach:

```
fun secondLast(x: String): String 
    = x.split("\n").takeLast(2).first()
```

The drawback of it, it will return the first line if the text will be 2 or 1 line long. In first case it is OK, but for 1-liner null could be more apropriate:

```
fun secondLast(x: String): String? =
    with(x.split("\n")) {
        if (size > 1) takeLast(2).first()
        else null
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one way beside the one mentioned. I have not added any check for `empty` or `size` as you said it will never be empty or less than 10 entries. But you can add check if needed just as easily.

```kotlin
fun String.secondLast(): String {
    return this.trim().split("\n").let { splitString ->
        splitString.elementAt(splitString.lastIndex - 1)
    }
}
```